# Does the Initiate of the Sevenfold Veil's Indigo Veil protect against supernatural abilities?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

The Initiate of the Sevenfold Veil (*Complete Arcane*) has a "Indigo Veil" ability which provides a protection against incoming spells and spell-like abilities:

> Indigo Veil: A 6th-level initiate can create the mighty indigo veil.
>   This veil prevents the passage of all spells or spell-like abilities.
>   Any creature crossing an indigo veil must succeed on a Will save or
>   become confused, as if by an insanity spell. A daylight spell negates
>   and is negated by an indigo veil. A warding with this veil is the
>   equivalent of a 7th-level spell.

Does this also protect them from supernatural abilities?

Answer (score 9):

No. A supernatural ability is not a spell-like ability, therefore it is not affected by the Indigo Veil which explicitly calls out spells and spell-like abilities.